# What features of x86, if any, allow a user-mode program to be aware that it is being debugged?

Tags: debugging, assembly, x86, obfuscation, anti-debugging

I seem to recall hearing in the past that an x86 program can detect whether it is being debugged. This was related to malware analysis.

Yet researching registers, I read up on the DRs and [found](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_debug_register) the statement:

> The debug registers are privileged resources; the MOV instructions
> that access them can only be executed at privilege level zero. An
> attempt to read or write the debug registers when executing at any
> other privilege level causes a general protection fault.

So, could someone explain perhaps if there is some alternative feature in x86 that allows a program to become aware that it is being debugged? I think I recall reading something about debuggers actually patching things into a program's instruction memory, but I'm not yet sure (I haven't had time to study the inner workings of a debugger yet).

Could someone clarify whether there is a fundamental feature of x86 that leaks information suggesting the attachment of a debugger to a program? Or perhaps it's just due to something more invasive debuggers might be doing?

Comment: TF (single-step Trap Flag) is part of EFLAGS, and setting software breakpoints will leave `0xcc int3` bytes in the machine code.  Having a look at any basic debug-detection example would show this, or mention it in comments.  Hardware breakpoints set with DR aren't directly observable to user-space code being debugged, AFAIK, but I think there are still some indirect things code can do to detect debuggers.  (Mainstream debuggers like GDB default to using software breakpoints.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Hmm, so due to the 15 byte limit (which I learned thanks to your 2016 comment "The ISA for 386 and later does impose a 15-byte limit."), could a program prevent its own debugging? As an answer put it: "For example, you can take the innocuous looking instruction:

`89 E5`              `mov %sp,%bp`
And turn it into a really long instruction:
`66 66 66 66 … 66 66 89 E5`                `mov %sp,%bp`" So couldn't we do this for every instruction in order to make it impossible for `0xcc` bytes to be appended?

Comment: Appended?  No, overwritten (and restored after the breakpoint is hit).  Memory is an array, not a linked list; you can't insert a byte and push all later bytes over by one, not without `memmove` of an unknown number of later bytes, and that would change their addresses, breaking PC-relative stuff and jump targets from elsewhere.

Comment: Ah, right. I was imaging 0xcc as some byte that could be added to an instruction without changing its behavior aside from adding an interrupt afterwards. I suppose this misunderstanding came from studying a bit about the [modular](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Kent-Griffin/publication/262272054/figure/fig2/AS:665149623001101@1535595436482/x86-instruction-format.png) nature of the x86 instruction.

Comment: That's true unless it's a jump, or it faults, in which case the `int3` would never be reached.  When you set a breakpoint on an instruction, you want to trap *before* it executes; that's how breakpoints work.  That's why debuggers replace the first byte of this instruction, not the first byte of the following instruction.  But regardless, `int3` is a separate instruction anyway, so instruction length is actually a non-issue, regardless of trying to append or prepend instead of just overwrite.  Seems like some practical experience using a debugger would help you think things through...

Answer (score 2):

No, there is *no* mechanism *built-in* into the x86 architecture allowing a program to *detect* whether it’s being debugged, but there are numerous *heuristics* allowing you to determine whether it’s *probably* being debugged, e.g.

- check `TracerPid` in `/proc/self/status` is nonzero,
- examine `rdtsc` difference (obviously generally unsuitable), or
- inspect the trap flag

but these methods aren’t infallible.
Ultimately it could be the case your program isn’t even run on a bare-metal x86 processor.